# Fetch Timestamp for last 12am in specific Timezone

Tags: javascript, datetime, time, timestamp

The problem at hand is to find out the generic timestamp last time it was 12 am in a specific timezone.

e.g. I want timestamp when it was last 12 am in India (IST).

Tried the following:

```
var IST = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 330*60*1000)
IST.setHours(0);
IST.setMinutes(0);
IST.setSeconds(0);
IST.setMilliseconds(0);
```

Turns out it returns the last time it was 12 am in GMT.

Answer (score 0):

When you use

```
new Date()
```

this gives the date in the current timezone. 
When you change your code to:

```
var UTC = new Date();
UTC.setUTCHours(UTC.getUTCHours());
UTC.setUTCMinutes(UTC.getUTCMinutes());
UTC.setUTCSeconds(UTC.getUTCSeconds());
UTC.setUTCMilliseconds(UTC.setUTCMilliseconds());
```

now UTC is set to current UTC time. Add time difference for eventual changes in date and set time to 00:00:00

```
UTC = new Date(UTC.getTime() + 330*60*1000);
UTC.setUTCHours(0);
UTC.setUTCMinutes(0);
UTC.setUTCSeconds(0);
UTC.setUTCMilliseconds(0);
```

you will get the last UTC 12 am. Add to this the time difference with the required timezone, and you should get the right time.

```
var IST = new Date(UTC.getTime() + 330*60*1000);
```

Comment: This is a wrong answer as when it was 23:30 on 3rd November 2015. The corresponding time in India was 05:00 on the 4th November.

Comment: Hence the answer is not this straight forward.

Comment: This should work when date changes as well (see updated answer)

Comment: Jevado, I figured out the solution to this problem. Will post it here soon.